# Case statement not satisfying the condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Requirment: 1.For class 12 if Gel pen is exists price of it else if ink pen exists ink pen price Inkpen price else if pen exists pen else pen price 2.For class 8 if ink pen is exists price of it else if pen exists pen price else null 3.For class 5 if pen is exists price of it else if pencil exists price of it else null 4.For class 3 if penicl is exists price of it else null

I tried to validate this conditions on SQL SERVER with CASE but return all the rows with matching condition. Any provide solution to validate this in SELECT or using any any other scope for this on ~1Million Data and kind of automating this.

Tables : Student

```
roll_no class
A   12
B   8
C   3
E   5
```

stationery

```
roll_no class obj   price
A       12   pen        10
A       12   pencil     5
A       12   ink pen    14
A       12   gel pen    16
B       8    ink pen    14
C       3    pencil     5
C       3    gel pen    16
E       5    gel pen    16
```

Result

```
A   16
B   14
C   5
D   Null
```

Answer (score 0):

It could use a nested `CASE WHEN` to calculate a priority for the prices.
And use a window function to get the price with highest priority.
Then aggregate.

> ```
> select roll_no, min(prio_price) as price
> from
> (
>     select *
>     , first_value(case when priority is not null then price end)  
>       over (partition by roll_no, class order by 10-priority desc) as prio_price
>     from stationary
>     cross apply (
>     select 
>     case class
>     when 12 
>     then case obj
>          when 'gel pen' then 1
>          when 'ink pen' then 2
>          when 'pen'     then 3
>          else 9
>          end
>     when 8 
>     then case obj
>          when 'ink pen' then 1
>          when 'pen'     then 2
>          end
>     when 5 
>     then case obj
>          when 'pen'    then 1
>          when 'pencil' then 2
>          end
>     when 3 
>     then case obj
>          when 'pencil' then 1
>          end
>     end as priority
>     ) p
> ) q
> group by roll_no
> order by roll_no;
> ```

> | roll_no | price |
> | --- | --- |
> | A | 16.00 |
> | B | 14.00 |
> | C | 5.00 |
> | D | *null* |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7702a23317580fdca28cbc631c6bffcc)*